# URLs with underscores are broken in preview, but not in actual question

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

The following URL

```
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/__init__.py
```

- live rendering: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/__init__.py

is shown like this in preview (broken)

- image: [image]

but like this in the actual question (okay)

- image: [image]

As a poster, one might get the idea of escaping the underscores with backslashes:

```
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/\_\_init__.py
```

- live rendering: [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/\_\_init__.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/%5C_%5C_init__.py)

which works in preview

- image: [image]

but not in the actual question (broken):

- image: [image: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/__init__.py]

Comment: You can get any raw link to work by surrounding it in `<` and `>`. The [GitHub onebox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394055/4642212) only works if you place the link in its own line; this is unrelated to the broken preview.

Comment: Imagine lacking parity between client-side and server-side Markdown parsers.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark.js/issues/176#issuecomment-549049021